# Hibernate 3 Maven plugin and Spring integeration

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven

I would like to use the Hibernate 3 Maven plugin in my project. However the plugin expects Hibernate.cfg file, which I don't have because Spring doesn't require one for Hibernate integration. does anyone knows a patch or a workaround to achieve that ?

If not, do you know any other plugin/script that will allow me to export the DB schema to a file (SQL or description file) from JPA annotated Pojos ?

Comment: Could you explain what Spring configuration have you done?

Comment: You can use the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file in a the spring application. Do you want to try that option?